# Find nested order of ul's and add specific classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out a way to loop through container like this

```
<nav id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <!-- And so on -->
          </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
    <li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and check how deep an ul is nested in so if its a first one add `class="level-1"` to it, if second `.level-2` etc. Bear in mind, each `<ul>` can contain more than one nested ul (multi level navigation).

Comment: @Satpal tried $('#container ul').each(index) and set ul class to value of the index, but obviously this doesn't do the trick. I can't figure out a way to check how deep in dom tree it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a9jrd8sn/3/)**

Simply iterate through the `ul`s and create a classname based on how many parent `ul`s each has, using [parentsUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) in case `#container` is within a `ul`.

```
$(function(){
    $('#container ul').each(function(){
        var classname = 'level-' + ($(this).parentsUntil('#container', 'ul').length + 1);
        $(this).addClass(classname);
    });
});
```

A slightly shorter way to write this (courtesy of Arun P Johny) is

```
$('#container ul').addClass(function(){
    return 'level-' + ($(this).parentsUntil('#container', 'ul').length + 1);
});
```

---

You originally included the CSS tag. If this is purely for CSS, you can just use CSS. See http://jsfiddle.net/a9jrd8sn/4/

Comment: Look into parentsUntil - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bb3L3jqr/1/ - as looking for all ul parents could cause problem if the `container` is in another `ul`

Comment: Replaced with `parentsUntil`